# In Laravel 7 How to orderBy Roles->name?

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have `User` Model  with `Roles relationships` like so :

```
public function users(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();

    }
```

And Role Model with user relationships :

```
public function roles(){

            return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withTimestamps();
        }
```

And of course Pivot Table   `"role_user"` contains `id, user_id, role_id and timestamps`

I try to get users `ordered By`  `roles name` like so :

```
$users = App\Models\User::with('roles')->orderBy('roles.name', 'desc')->get();
```

but i have this error :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.name' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null order by `roles`.`name` desc)
http://localhost:8000/users
```

Please, some helps .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older question I stumbled upon, but be aware that when using `->with()`, the Query Builder doesn't perform any kind of `join ...` query, so `roles.name` is indeed not available as you currently have your query written.

If you want to order by `roles.name` in SQL, then you need to manually join `roles` to `users` (via the `role_user` pivot table), then do `orderBy('roles.name')`:

```
$users = App\Models\User::select('users.*')
->with('roles')
->join('role_user', 'role_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->join('roles', 'role_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
->orderBy('roles.name', 'DESC')
->get();
```

*Note: I still used `->with('roles')` so that `$user->roles` is still available as a `Collection`.*

Documentation can be found here:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins (your version)

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#joins (current version)

Additionally, while `sortBy()` is another valid option (as illustrated by the other answer here), using `Model::get()->sortBy(...)` for larger datasets is a potential memory/timeout issue, as it requires loading *every single record from your database table into PHP's memory*, then using PHP logic for sorting.

Answer (score -1):

Try Like this:

```
$users = App\Models\User::with('roles')->get();
// order of the roles
$array = ['User','Admin','Doctor', 'Manager']; 
$sorted = $users->sortBy(function($model) use ($array) {
    return array_search($model['roles'], $array);
});
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: what you want then?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes, it only works to order roles for the same user, but I want to sort all the users have user role then all users have a super role, then  users have a role of doctor then users have admin role

Comment: this is the result of your answer  [Imgur](https://imgur.com/xIHwjXN)
but i want to have order the table by Role column

Comment: Ok,
For the variable $array i used it like this $array = App\Models\Role::get('name')->toarray();  is this right ?
What is $market ?

Comment: sorry it will be `$user` that was mistake!